# how to pass in and out parameters to a mysql stored procedure and return the stored procedure result in the nodejs code

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures

```
connection.query("call vts_active_tagid('"+RFIDNumber+"','"+Latitude+"','"+Longitude+"','"+datetime+"','"+imeno+"',@passengers,@trip)");
```

this stored procedure gives one output which contains firstname,phone number and passengerid,how to get those values in the nodejs code

Answer (score 15):

1. First thing first, set your mysql to accept multiple statement

   `set mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});`
2. Do your query

   `query_str = "CALL sp_whatever(?,?,?,@output); select @output";
    con.query(query_str, [param1, param2, param3], function(err,rows){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(rows);
    });`

Output:

```
[OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 0,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 10,
    warningCount: 0,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0 },
  [ RowDataPacket { '@output': -2 } ] ]
```

Answer (score 3):

a sample for you

```
dbConnection.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        var edituserSQL =  "CALL spEditTheme(?,?,?,?)";
        var resultt;
        connection.query(edituserSQL, [ object.selfid,object.theme_background,object.theme_foreground,dateTimeNow ], function(ERROR,RESULT) {
                if (ERROR) {
                    cb(ERROR, null);
                } else {
                    console.log("exEditUserTheme result");
                    console.log(RESULT);
                    var account = RESULT[0][0].result;
                    cb(null, account);
                }
            });

            connection.release();
    });
```

Comment: where did you pass out parameter and get it's value?

Comment: Where is the out parameter?  It looks to me that you only passed IN params.

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs code:

```
con.query("CALL sp_ReturnValue(?, @ret_value); CALL sp_ReadReturnValue;", [id], (err, rows) => {
                if (!err && rows[0].affectedrows != 0) {
                    console.log("Print return value ", rows[1][0].ret_value); 
                } 
            })
```

Stored procedure with input and output parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_ReturnValue`(
    p_Id int(11),                -- Input param
    OUT r_status INT(11)               -- output param
)
BEGIN 
    SELECT Status FROM tblUsers WHERE tblUsers_ID = p_Id; // use of input param
      SET r_status = 2; // use of output param
END
```

Reading return value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_ReadReturnValue`()
BEGIN
    SELECT @ret_value AS ret_value;
END
```

You can also read value without stored procedure like:

```
SELECT @ret_value AS ret_value;
```

Example:

```
con.query("CALL sp_ReturnValue(?, @ret_value); SELECT @ret_value AS ret_value", [id], (err, rows) => {
                    console.log("Print return value ", rows[1][0].ret_value);  
            })
```

You also could return multiple values like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_ReturnValue`(
    p_Id int(11),                -- Input param
    OUT r_status1 INT(11)               -- output param
    OUT r_status2 VARCHAR(11)               -- output param
    OUT r_status3 INT(11)               -- output param
)
BEGIN 
    SELECT Status FROM tblUsers WHERE tblUsers_ID = p_Id; // use of input param
      SET r_status1 = 2; // use of output param
      SET r_status2 = "ABCD"; // use of string output param
      SET r_status3 = 2; // use of output param
END
```

And READ like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_ReadReturnValue`()
BEGIN
    SELECT @ret_value1 AS ret_value1,
           @ret_value2 AS ret_value2,
           @ret_value3 AS ret_value3;
END
```

Parameter in node for Out param:

```
con.query("CALL sp_ReturnValue(?, @ret_value1, @ret_value2, @ret_value3); CALL sp_ReadReturnValue;", [id], (err, rows) => {
            console.log("Print return value \n "); 
            console.log(rows[1][0].ret_value1 "\n");  
            console.log(rows[1][0].ret_value2 "\n");
            console.log(rows[1][0].ret_value3 );
    })
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question with just code, even if right, try to explain it a little bit. In your case, there are some other answers, so please, show the Pros of your P.O.V.

Answer (score 0):

let sql=`CALL storedproc(${rfidnumber},${latitude},${longitude},${date})`

connection.query(sql,(error, results, fields)={
if(error) throw error
response.send(results[0])
})

Comment: it would be nice to improve your answer via proper formatting and at least a little sentence on what is going on.