# How to run mysql stored procedure with output return in knex.js

Tags: mysql, api, knex.js

I have a problem with knex.js

how to call stored procedure with output in knex.js

sp string : call sp_start(1, @outmsg);

I need call that SP and select the output in return

my code:

```
    .get('/:headerId/recount', function(req, res, next) {

    knex.raw(
    'Call sp_start(?,?)',[req.params.headerId, @outmsg]
    )
    .then(function(result) {
       return; 
        });
  })
```

but it return error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [how to pass in and out parameters to a mysql stored procedure and return the stored procedure result in the nodejs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299321/how-to-pass-in-and-out-parameters-to-a-mysql-stored-procedure-and-return-the-sto/27456523)

```
knex.transaction(trx => {
  return knex.raw(
    'Call sp_start(?,@outmsg)',
    [req.params.headerId]
  )
  .then(res => knex.select(knex.raw('@outmsg')));
})
.then(res => console.log("Got output:", res));
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

I am using an Express server with route/service. The above answer didn't work for me.

What did work was using a multiple statement raw method like so:

```
ExpressService(knex, param){
  return knex.raw(`call sp_start(${param}, @outmsg); select @outmsg as outmsg;`);
};
```

You will also need to add `multipleStatements: true` to your MySQL connection.

Comment: Passing raw params from ExpressJS right into a Template Literal for knex.raw is very dangerous. This should work and protect from SQL injection `knex.raw('call sp_start(?, @outmsg); select @outmsg as outmsg;', [param])`