# How do you receive a MySQL Stored Procedure OUT parameter as a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql

Disclaimer; my background is in C#, so I'm not familiar with JavaScript more than at a cursory level; however, I was reviewing some code with one of our developers today and he was receiving some strange behavior of return results "merging" with pre-existing return results. I was very surprised to see every single JavaScript example of calling a Stored Procedure uses a Global Variable on the MySQL side to store the out parameter! This blows my mind and IMO is a big "no no" relative to writing code. Take the below example:

```
exports.updateRasSql = 'CALL update_ras_data(?, ?, @out_result, @out_result_value);
```

What it comes down to is we do NOT want to assign the OUT parameter variables to a MySQL global variable. We want the OUT values to be assigned to internal JavaScript variables, but any time we try to do this (using var or let as a definer), MySQL returns:

```
Error: ER_SP_NOT_VAR_ARG: OUT or INOUT argument 3 for routine empowercrm_main.update_ras_data is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger
```

**So here's the question: How do we call a MySQL Stored Procedure from Node/JavaScript and have it return the OUT variables to internal JavaScript variables and not MySQL global variables?**

Comment: look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41236394/5193536

Comment: @nbk Interesting; so that example shows him using object.xx as the receiving method; but I can't find examples of that anywhere else. Do you have additional details on this?

Comment: no i looked at some rewsults of the search and this seems understandable und easy to implement. but search for your self andsee hwat other people wrote. but javascript under stand multi quety and so that is easy th´o inderstand and to use., you could so also get 3 or 4 userdefined variales back or two tables, if the procedure woud have such returns.

Answer (score 0):

You should return a result set (make query in a procedure) instead of using `OUT`-variables. The only way of getting the value of a OUT-variable is to select it after you have executed the procedure. It's easier just to handle the result set.

Comment: Many of our stored procedures execute business logic and return no result sets, but instead result details - and we're using JSON to encapsulate those results, so your recommendation wouldn't apply to our numerous stored procedures that solely execute business logic with details on that execution in JSON format.

Regardless, the core question is it even possible to have the OUT parameters write directly to JavaScript variables for server-side code processing?

Comment: It is not. What you can do is to do `select @out_result_value` after the procedure execution or create a wrapped procedure which first calls your original procedure and then selects the OUT-variable. For future, you should consider using result sets instead or OUT variables.